# how to make Isotope to shuffle when after last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am facing a little problem with isotope plug-in. Isotope shuffle when the browser width touch the right side of an element, I would like to change it and make it shuffle when the browser width is in the middle of the element. Is it possible ? do I need to modify the plug-in for that ? thanks

```
                //implement isotope card flow plugin
            $('.isotope').isotope({
                // options
                itemSelector: '.momentsinside',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
```

Comment: What efforts have you put forth to resolve this?

Comment: I looked into the documentation http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html

Comment: there is for sure somewhere here an Isotope expert

Comment: What do you mean "when the browser width is in the middle of the element."

Comment: I want to make the same thing as as in Pinterest, try to resize the browser on Pinterest and you will see what I mean. The cards are shuffling when the browser is in the middle of a card

Comment: OK, what does this mean, "browser is in the middle of a card"? It makes no sense. You need to be clearer what you want. Do you just want the items to re-arrange when the browser window changes size or do you want the items to be responsive?

Comment: I want the item to re-arrange when the browser window changes